# Ftp to external server in azure webjob not working

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs

I have a code which runs fine in local machine however in Azure it throws "Unable to connect to remote server", I 'm getting data from sql,processing it, and then uploading to a external server via ftp, is there any settings needs to be done for FTP in Azure ?

Code :

```
FtpWebRequest request =
    (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.example.com/remote/path/file.zip");
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;  

using (Stream fileStream = File.OpenRead(csvfilestring))
using (Stream ftpStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    fileStream.CopyTo(ftpStream);
}
```

Comment: Any Azure Expert please help

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the azure webjob, the `FtpWebRequest` instance configure the application so it dialog with the external FTP server using a public IP adress to get a socket to upload the files. So check what you port you are using.

If you have not tried the following steps described in [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2014/08/01/microsoft-azure-web-site-connect-to-your-site-via-ftp-and-uploaddownload-files/), kindly try to do that and let us know the status.

Also, you could [enable the diagnostics log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log) for web app and check the log where you have the problem.